# Тест производительности выдает ошибку. Для данного домена нет данных. Выберите другой домен из списка?

Tags: битрикс

Хочу протестировать скорость сайта, но при заходе на страницу ***Производительность->Скорость*** сайта сразу пишет "Для данного домена нет данных. Выберите другой домен из списка" в чем может быть причина данного сообщения ?

Comment: А селект переключения сайтов есть?